# Why are changes to the QML code sometimes not reflected when hitting 'Run' and how to solve it?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qmake

In this Qt Quick simple example, I want that when I move a Racked upwards, we have a message on *console.log* showing that movement and another message when the Racket is moved downwards. I've written this code for that:

`Racket.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 15; height: 50
    x: 400; y: 100
    color: "red"

    property int oldY: 100
    property bool yUwards: false
    property bool yDwards: false

        onYChanged: {
           if( y > oldY) {
              yDwards = true
              yUwards = false
              console.log("Racket moved downwards.\n")
            }

           else if( y < oldY) {
               yDwards = false
               yUwards = true
               console.log("Racket moved upwards.\n")
             }
            oldY = y
        }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: root
        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        drag.minimumY: 10
        drag.maximumY: 440
    }
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id: table
        width: 700; height: 500
        border.width: 10
        border.color: "black"
        color: "white"

   Racket {
       id: redRacket
       x: 630; y: 100
       color: "red"
    }
  }
}
```

When I at the first time hit `Run`, the code didn't work, so I hit `clean all`, `run qmake` and then `rebuild all`, then it worked!
How does a new QML programmer like me figure out that the code is fine but this process is needed to successfully run the program?

Comment: So what is your question? If you want to complain you should contact the developers or open a case in bugtracker.

Comment: @folibis: It might not be worded perfectly, but it is a question that regularly appears for new QML programmers, as it is not transparent, not documented, and there are work arounds. I think with some help it might become a pretty helpful question for other people.

Comment: As it has nothing to do with the posted code, I would remove the code. Instead describe what you have experienced: When you change which files, the problem appears? Is it in any file (including main.qml, cpp files, main.cpp) or just in some other files like `MyCustomComponent.qml`? Do you have your project setup to use `qrc` for qml files or not? Maybe post the content of the `main.cpp`. But other than that: State the problem only. If you found the "`clean all, run qmake, rebuild all`" as your solution, post it as a first answer. If someone has a better answer, he might still provide it.

Comment: If you're using .qrc files, then it's probably the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320093/qt-does-not-update-ui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029621/rebuilding-again-and-again-to-view-the-imported-qml-file-changes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944219/how-to-always-compile-a-file: the root cause is https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a bug in QMake.
As @Mitch posted in his comment, a bug report was already filed: [bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334)

If you read through the comments in that bug report, a workaround for the problem was posted. Have been using it for a couple of months now and it seems to fix the issue.
All you have to do is paste this at the end of your pro file.

```
#update qml
qml_scenes.depends = $$PWD/resources/scene1.qml $$PWD/resources/scene2.qml ...
qml_scenes.commands =
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += qml_scenes
```