# Qt Creator wrongly picks up file types, and ignores modifications to these files

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator

I am including some javascript file, importing them as library in a qml file. The first file I created is picked up right: the syntax hilight looks ok, and any change to that file gets reflected in a recompile.
But this is not true for two other files.
Syntax hilight differs in this way (this is in my qml file):

```
import "qrc:/themes/PxDefaultTheme.js" as PxTheme;  // "good" file
import "qrc:/themes/PxQtDefaults.js" as PxQtDefaults;  // "bad" file
```

The "PxTheme" word is hilighted in blue, italic. Changes to it are reflected after recompile.
"PxQtDefaults" is purple, non-italic (like a regular Qt object). Changes to it are ignored.
I am using Qt creator 4.9.2.

I have tried the following:

- deleted the .pro.user and build directory (many times!), no effect
- changed the import order, no effect
- changed the file names, no effect
- tried to re-start from a clean start:

  - deleted the two "bad" files,
  - put their content in the first "good" one,
  - import that single "good" file: all is ok
  - copy the "good" file exactly as is, in one of the other file
  - brand new copied "bad" file is still hilighted wrongly, and ignored

Yesterday the situation was even worse, as Qt was telling me it could not import the "bad" files. After hours of playing around, I can now import all. On a rebuild, the 3 files content is taken in properly.

For simplicity's sake, I'm just going to show two files, a "good" and a "bad" one.
So in my PxStyle.qml file, I import these .js files as described above.
My qrc's content for these two files is:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
... [more files] ...
        <file>styles/PxStyle.qml</file>
        <file>themes/PxDefaultTheme.js</file>
        <file>themes/PxQtDefaults.js</file>
... [more files] ...
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I've trimmed these two files to their bare minimum:

PxDefaultTheme.js:

```
// PxDefaultTheme.js
.pragma library;
let backgroundColor = "lightblue";
```

PxQtDefaults.js:

```
// PxQtDefaults.js
.pragma library;
const color = "#ffffff";
```

Is there some other information hidden somewhere, concerning my project?
Thanks.

---

**Edit 08/11/2019**

This might be a mix of different issues, related to Qt Creator problems under Windows.

This morning, syntax highlighting is ok (all `as XXXX` names are in blue, italic), and all file modifications are picked up ok.

I cannot explain the syntax highlight (beside it being a bug).

But for the file modifications being integrating in each compile, this might be linked to an issue coming up over and over again concerning creator: [Why are changes to the QML code sometimes not reflected when hitting 'Run' and how to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810450/why-are-changes-to-the-qml-code-sometimes-not-reflected-when-hitting-run-and-h), [QT QML resource files do not recompile after changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828015/qt-qml-resource-files-do-not-recompile-after-changes), etc... which leads to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334.

All I did here is go for a Windows real cold boot (forcing Windows to really shutdown, `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 0`).

This step seems to have brought things back to normal. I will experiment with the `qml_scenes` settings and update this post if I find more.

Anyone know if this `qml_scenes` setting is documented anywhere? Matt's answer to one of the post above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889495/9316077) shows how to dive recursively into directories, is this documented?

Comment: Why is the `qrc:/` prefix required? Since `main.qml` is also a resource, the JavaScript imports should be relative references, i.e. `import "themes/PxDefaultTheme.js" as PxTheme; `

Comment: I just like to have absolute paths, this way I can refactor things without worrying about that.